# Installing Windows 10 Build 1607 on a VMWare Workstation 9 fails with KMODE EXCEPTION NOT HANDLED

Tags: windows-10, vmware-workstation, windows-10-v1607

The host OS is a Windows 10 1607 64bit machine.

I try to install the Windows 10 Build 1607 64bit on a Vmware 9 Workstation.

I get an error when the machine reboots: KMODE EXCEPTION NOT HANDLED

Installing Windows 10 64bit Build 1511 works.

Is there any setting I can change in VMWare 9.

Edit 2016-11-24: I just tried the 32bit Version of Build 1607, same problem.

Comment: I believe there is a bug in the newest Windows 10 build (1607) that causes virtualization cores to bug giving you KMODE EXCEPTION NOT HANDLED aka blue screen. Did you try installing Windows 10 1511 build and just update from there?

Comment: Host OS and version?

Comment: Have you tried the current version of VMWare Workstation, to see if its simply a conflict, between VMWare Workstation 9 and Windows 10 Version 1607?

Comment: @Argonauts It is a Windows 10 1607 too. I just changed my question.

Comment: @Ramhound: I have only a license for VMWare 9.

Comment: Exact same problem here.  I'm anticipating planned obsolescence is the issue.  Anybody know if 1607 works on workstation 10+

Comment: I have the same problem with Workstation 12 Pro and Windows 10 1607. I just want to confirm that installing an earlier version of Windows does not help. As soon as you try to update to 1607 with Windows Update you get stuck in the KMODE EXCEPTION loop.

Comment: Same problem here VMWare Workstation 9 upgrade from 1511 to 1607.

Comment: Same problem here on VMWare Workstation 10...

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is to upgrade to VMWare Workstation 12.5:
https://blogs.vmware.com/workstation/2016/08/workstation-12-5-announced.html

I was in the middle of a reboot loop with Workstation 10 and the "kmode..." error and simply upgrading Workstation to 12.5.2 continued the anniversaty update on it's way without doing anything else, other than powering on the guest.

I messed with this W10 anniversary update and Workstation 10 for three days and tried the iso download/upgrade and uninstalling all the non-essential Workstation devices, no other programs/W10 devices installed, resizing partitions... literally every suggestion on the net...

Workstation 12.5 (or I'm guessing Player 12.5) is the fix.